# jQuery: changing a string of HTML before it displays

Tags: jquery

I am working on a front end script that copies and then outputs the HTML as plain text, I have got that part working in my Fiddle below.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/94tLL4e7/10/)

My question, is there a way I can change the output string **before it displays** e.g. in my Fiddle example change the word "test" to "boat" and change the URL "http://www.linkedin.com" to "http://www.google.com" just as an example.

```
$('.output').click(function () {
    $('.outputCon').css('display', 'block');
    var $code = $('.redCon').html();
    $('.outputCon').text($code);
});
```

I have been looking at a few string replacement code options:

```
$('.outputCon').html($($code).html().replace('test', 'dog'));
```

Which I am not sure if I have done correctly as I am not sure how to implement this to change the string before the HTML has been displayed, sorry my explanation is hard to follow, ill happily answer any questions.

Comment: `$code` is already an HTML string, so you could simply do `$('.outputCon').html($code.replace('test', 'dog'));`

Comment: Thanks heaps, that now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable `$code` already contains the html text so you can use the replace method on that. Instead of:

```
$('.outputCon').html($($code).html().replace('test', 'dog'));
```

you can just do this:

```
$('.outputCon').text($code.replace('test','dog'));
```

Also, it seems like you're mixing up PHP with jQuery; you don't need to use `$` for variables in jQuery.

Comment: A quick question, when I add more than one instance of something to replace it skips all above and just replaces the last https://jsfiddle.net/kellyhawker/94tLL4e7/14/ is there a better way of replacing multiple strings

Comment: Is this in reference to the link? Did you want LINKEDIN hyperlink to go to http://www.google.com ?

Comment: Sorry, that was just an example, it has no relevance to anything but I just found my answer so I am all good now, thanks again.